# how to Set Border on image in swift not on uiimageview?

Tags: iphone, swift

i want to draw a border on image in app ,  i am able to draw a border on uiimageview , but i required image theme  border (according to image set in image view image border will set)

Please suggest how to do it.

Thanks in Advance.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make an extension to `UIImage` like this:

```
extension UIImage {
  func imageByAddingBorder(borderWidth width: CGFloat, borderColor color: UIColor) -> UIImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.size)
    let imageRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.size.width, height: self.size.height)
    self.drawInRect(imageRect)

    let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    let borderRect = CGRectInset(imageRect, width / 2, width / 2)

    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(ctx, color.CGColor)
    CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, width)
    CGContextStrokeRect(ctx, borderRect)

    let borderedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return borderedImage
  }
}
```

It can be used like this:

```
let birdImage = UIImage(named: "bird")
imageView.image = birdImage!.imageByAddingBorder(borderWidth: 100.0, borderColor: UIColor.redColor())
```